# How can I find my Emacs init file?

Tags: init-file

I have read the guide found here:

[How Emacs Finds Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init)

I cannot find any `.emacs` directory in my home directory.  I have `show hidden files` selected. I also cannot find the `init.el` file in Emacs home directory.

Since I have been unable to find the `init.el` file, is it reasonable to think there isn't one?

I am using Emacs 27.1 on Windows 10. Except for Emacs home directory I installed with the defaults. I used no command-line options during install.

I seem to remember I have once read a post which explained Emacs has an internal variable which is used to hold the value of the location of where Emacs found the `init.el` file after it starts, but after searches I have been unable to find what that variable is.

How can I find my `init.el` file, having failed to locate it in the locations mentioned in the manual?

Does a variable exist which says where the `init.el` file was found? If so, what is it?

Comment: You might like to clarify why you think there should be a `.emacs` *directory* (AFAIK there can be a `.emacs` *file* or a `.emacs.d` directory, but I've never heard of a `.emacs` directory).  Similarly clarify what you mean by "Emacs home directory".

Comment: `C-h v` and then `user-init-file` will show you what your current user init file is

Comment: Thanks @minibuffer. I have looked at the variable and it says "Its value is "~/.emacs"". I cannot fine a file of that name. What does this mean?

Comment: That is because windows (usually) sets $HOME as %APPDATA% and puts your `.emacs` file in there. So in Windows ~ usually meanss %APPDATA%. In a windows cmd prompt do `cd %APPDATA%`. You will most likely find your `.emacs` file in there.

Comment: @minubuffer. Excellent! Yes, I have found the `emacs.d` directory there. In it are the `auto-save-list` directory and the `elpa` directory. In `elpa` there is `archives\gnu\archive-conitents`. Why can't I find an init file here though?

Comment: well you might not have an `.emacs` file. Create an `init.el` file *inside* the `.emacs.d` directory that you just found. put some sample config on there and see if emacs picks it up. For example `(setq initial-scratch-message "Hello from my new init file :)")`

Comment: @minibuffer, you're a genius. Thank you! That really, really helped. My next question was to be "Now how do I make a test file?", and you preempted it. Yes, I tried your idea. I wasn't sure where the message would appear at first but I soon found it in the *scratch* buffer. Great! I am now ready to start learning elisp. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @minibuffer, how do I accept your answer as the one I was looking for?

Comment: Glad it helped. I will consolidate the comments into an answer when I have a bit of time.

Comment: you can customize the emacs theme from the option menu and also save the option.
start over emacs with new theme, and look for .init or .emacs in .emacs.d folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10545955/324105 might also prove useful for this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer specifically address the question of how/where to find Emacs'
`user-init-file` on Microsoft Windows.

### HOME and Startup Directories on MS-Windows

Here is the relavent section from the Emacs manual (available via `C-h i`)
Emacs > Microsoft Windows > Windows Home

> The Windows equivalent of `HOME` is the `user-specific application data directory`. The actual location depends on the Windows version;
> ... `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming` on Windows Vista and later ...
> If this directory does not exist or cannot be accessed, Emacs falls
> back to `C:\` as the default value of ‘HOME’.

This location is stored in the environment variable that windows
refers to as `%APPDATA%`. See this question and
[answer](https://superuser.com/questions/632891/what-is-appdata) on
`superuser`

You can try to find the location of your `user-init-file` by doing `C-h v` and
then `user-init-file [RET]`. You will see an output similar to

```
~/.emacs
```

On Windows this isn't particularly helpful. We can now find out what
Emacs means by `~` doing one of the following:

`C-x C-f` > `~` > `[backspace]`
The `echo` area at the bottom of your Emacs screen will expand to show
you what Emacs currently consider to be HOME. (Note that this works on
Windows and according to @NickD doesn't work on GNU/Linux)

OR more generally (quoting from the Emacs manual)

> You can always find out what Emacs thinks is your home directory’s
> location by typing `C-x d ~/ <RET>`.  This should present the list of
> files in the home directory, and show its full name on the first line.
> Likewise, to visit your init file, type `C-x C-f ~/.emacs <RET>`
> (assuming the file’s name is `.emacs`).

---

### Setting up the `init.el` on Windows

Instead of keeping a `.emacs` file most emacs users now use an
`init.el` file stored in your `user-emacs-directory`. This directory
defaults to `~/.emacs.d` and in your case
`%APPDATA%/.emacs.d/`. Assuming you don't already have a `.emacs` file
stored in `%APPDATA%/` You can now go ahead and create an `init.el`
file *inside* the `.emacs.d` directory. Put some sample configuration
in your `init.el` file and see if Emacs picks it up when you re-start
Emacs. Also see this
[this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12884/13976) answer on Emacs
Stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive solution, minibuffer. I had wondered one thing though, like NickD I don't know if I have understood the [backspace] instruction, or if it works differently for the Windows default. When I press backspace, it only deletes the tilde.

Comment: Well on my keyboard when I hit backspace on `~` in the minibuffer it expands to show me the absolute path. In any case, you have an alternate way to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes, once you mentioned `%APPDATA%`, I merely typed `echo %APPDATA%` on the command line, and on seeing the variable was defined, I did `cd %APPDATA%` to visit the directory and found the `.emacs.d` directory there. In it I put the test `init.el` file you recommended, which contains only `(setq initial-scratch-message "Hello from my new init file :)")` and I then launched emacs and found the test message in the scratch buffer, confirming the process works, at least for me. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Thanks very much for this, very helpful. However, not sure if this variable changed recently or not but on Emacs 27.1 its ```user-emacs-directory``` rather than ```emacs-user-directory```.

Comment: @MarcoCraveiro: You are right. It should be `user-emacs-directory`. Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

The variable is `user-init-file`. Its doc string says:

> File name, including directory, of user’s initialization file.
> If the file loaded had extension ‘.elc’, and the corresponding source file
> exists, this variable contains the name of source file, suitable for use
> by functions like ‘custom-save-all’ which edit the init file.
> While Emacs loads and evaluates any init file, value is the real name
> of the file, regardless of whether or not it has the ‘.elc’ extension.

EDIT: If the value of the variable is non-nil, as in your case, it means that it actually found the file `~/.emacs` somewhere, somehow. I don't know much about Windows, but if you look in what you think is your home directory and cannot find a file called `.emacs`, it might be that some translation is going on. ISTR, that in some cases, on Windows, the file name was `_emacs`, but that was a long time ago, in a universe far, far away, and I may very well be wrong.

See if [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html) helps: it describes how the HOME directory is determined on Windows.

Also, the method that @minibuffer describes in a comment might well be the best way to find the file: do `C-x C-f ~/ RET`  and look at the pathname at the top of the directory listing (this is slightly different from what the comment describes, but I couldn't get the `backspace` method to work for me: it just deletes the `~` in the prompt - but this is on Linux, and Windows may behave differently).

Comment: Thank you. It says "Its value is "~/.emacs". I have looked in my home directory and I cannot find a file with that name. What does this mean?

Comment: In addition to my earlier comment you can also do `C-x C-f` and then `~` and then hit `backspace` this will expand to show you the absolute path of what emacs means by `~`.

Comment: @minibuffer. Yes, I can do that! This is very helpful. Thank you. I can go directly to the directory within emacs without having to search for it. In that directory structure though  I still cannot find the init file. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create or open an an existing init file when opening ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el. ~ is a macro character which expand to the correct directory.
On a fresh install you have to create an init file.

Comment: Your answer may mean currently there is no init file. I didn't create one. I assumed there would be a default copy. Is it reasonable to believe as I haven't created one that there is no emacs init file on my computer?