# What steps should I take to troubleshoot use-package not loading packages

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, use-package, emacs-29

I'm using emacs 29.1 on Windows.
I have extracted the emacs folder to a corporate OneDrive.
I have a home folder set up with `emacs-29.1\share\emacs\site-lisp\site-start.el`
with `(setenv "HOME" "C:\\path to my corp one drive \\HOME\\")`

I store packages in
`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")`

Unfortunately whenever I try to use use-package I get error
`Error (use-package): Cannot load xyz-package`
packages tested are org-drill and org-roam.

steps taken:

- uninstalled and installed packages again.
- tried launching `runemacs.exe --debug-init` (no additional info except the `Error (use-package)`
- tried using
  `(add-to-list 'load-path ('org-drill "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-drill-20210427.2003/"))`

`(require 'org-drill)`

- instead when evaluating `.emacs file error is: invalid function 'org-drill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first to set a correct `$HOME` environment variable - see
[this](https://superuser.com/questions/1319038/how-to-set-home-variable-so-that-cmd-find-the-path) or
[this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60127/how-can-i-find-my-emacs-init-file)
links.

Next, you need to add MELPA repository to your `init.el` file, since not all
packages are available on the default emacs repository, as in below snippet:

```lisp
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu-elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/")
        ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))

;; Highest number gets priority (what is not mentioned has priority 0)
(setq package-archive-priorities
      '(("gnu-elpa" . 3)
        ("melpa" . 2)
        ("nongnu" . 1)))

(package-initialize)
```

and then you must be sure the `use-package` is available and then you
must load it, to become operative:

````lisp
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
;; On Emacs version 29 ```use-package``` is built-in, so the previous
;; three lines can be avoided, an the next one is mandatory:
(require 'use-package)
````

Now you can ask for other packages(`org-drill` is available in MELPA):

```lisp
(use-package org-drill
;; the rest of configuration
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  

It did work. 
I kept the `HOME`  setup from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6692788)
It was enough to set package-archives and `(package-initialize)`