# Emacs doesn't pick up .emacs.d/ on windows

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows

I'm using Linux at home but for work reasons I need to use Windows. That's why I've installed emacs on my company computer. I have a implemented at several scripts at home to be able to replicate my exact emacs setup when I switch to new computers.

According to this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/how-do-i-set-up-my-emacs-d-folder-on-windows) I've created a `HOME` variable pointing to `AppData\Roaming`. Is the right location for the `.emacs.d` directory? How can I check on windows the default location emacs is looking for an `.emcas.d`, `init.el` etc? However, I think `AppData\Roaming` seems to be the right place, as I see a that emacs has created a `.emacs` file within that directory.

Nevertheless, emacs is not evaluating the `.emacs.d/init.el`. That file contains a list of packages and layout option which I use per default. If packages are not installed it will install it. However, nothing happens when I open Emacs and the layout is also not adjusted. Since I'm not a Windows expert and I've already set up the `HOME` environment variable, what else can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Menu Bar->Help->Read the Emacs manual`
2. `Menu Bar -> Index -> Lookup a string and display index of results...`
3. Type `ms-windows` when prompted
4. You will see an entry like the following

```
* _emacs init file, MS-Windows [Concept Index]: Windows HOME. (line 43)
```

5. Clicking on that will give you the information you need.  The information you see will be same as this one [HOME and Startup Directories on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html)

The above page says

> You can always find out what Emacs thinks is your home directory’s location by typing `C-x d ~/ RET`. This should present the list of files in the home directory, and show its full name on the first line. Likewise, to visit your init file, type `C-x C-f ~/.emacs RET` (assuming the file’s name is `.emacs`).